# .NET Tizen and SignalR

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, signalr, tizen

I am building a Tizen App (`.NET Tizen 4.0`) using .NET Core and Xamarin (https://docs.tizen.org/application/dotnet/).

Everything works perfectly fine, except for one thing. It is impossible to start an SignalR (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client (5.0.7)`) connection to a hub. As soon as I create a new HubConnectionBuilder the following exception gets thrown:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The weirdest part about this. This exception changes without me doing anything. If I grab a drink for example, come back and run it again a different assembly is missing. For now I saw either `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1` or `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0` missing. To top it off: I do not use either of those packages actively.

So basically, as soon as I remove the following line of code, everything works fine.

```cs
this.hub = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl($"wss://{Settings.Instance.ServerAddress}/deviceHub").Build();
```

I already tried to add the missing packages, but without success. The thing is, the packages, for some super strange reason, cannot be found in the SignalR.Client package (just my guess). I also tried removing SignalR.Client, Rebuilding the Project, Uninstalling Tizen from Visual Studio, Update all my packages and even uninstalled Visual Studio. I literally wasted my last 3 days on this without any progress. Maybe someone has a solution to this, or some sort of workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error might be due to the notorious assembly version mismatch problem on Tizen devices.

https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/blog/en-us/2020/02/17/assembly-loading-problem-in-tizen-net-applications

Explanation: Tizen 4.0 devices come with the pre-installed `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll` assembly of the version **4.1.1.0**, but the latest *Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client* nuget package depends on `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll` of **4.2.1.0**. So the app will break because the runtime host always resolves the pre-installed assembly first. (The same app will run without problem on Tizen 5.5 devices because the pre-installed assembly version is 4.3.1.0.) However, I'm not sure why `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll` couldn't be resolved since it's not part of the .NET Core runtime and not pre-installed with Tizen devices.

In short, you may add the following event handler your app's Main() and check if the problem persists.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (object s, ResolveEventArgs eventArgs) =>
    {
        var appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(App).Assembly.Location);
        var assemblyName = eventArgs.Name.Split(',')[0];
        var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(appDir, assemblyName + ".dll");
        return File.Exists(assemblyPath) ? Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath) : null;
    };
    ..
    app.Run(args);
}
```

Please make sure the `http://tizen.org/metadata/prefer_dotnet_aot` metadata value is not set in `tizen-manifest.xml` when applying this change. If it's set, you need to change `assemblyPath` to something like `Path.Combine(appDir, ".native_image", assemblyName + ".ni.dll")`.

Please let me know if this doesn't fix your error.

Comment: Thank you so incredibly much! This 7 lines of code worked like magic. Copy and paste and it just worked! I expected something like that, but that default behavior, for me, does not make any sense, since the app is already delivered with the baked in newer version. `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll` is also found now. I think it was displayed randomly because of this weird behavior, because, as you said, it is not part of .NET Core.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't make any sense. On desktops, the runtime host (.NET CLI) resolves dependent assemblies using a .deps.json file right before an app is launched, but that's not possible on Tizen (shame on it) for performance reasons - the runtime is initialized before the launch request arrives and even prefetches some pre-installed assemblies. I requested a fix to the runtime team quite a while ago but there wasn't a good solution that worked for all possible cases. Anyway, I feel very sorry for wasting your precious time.